# Why properties are always added in middle

Tags: java, spring, collections, properties

I am trying to update properties file as below.

```
        Properties props = new Properties();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
        props.setProperty(key, value);
        props.store(out,"fileupdated");

        out.close();
```

But always I notice that newly added properties are added some where in middle of the file and I want it to be added only at the end. Please advise how should I resolve this.

Also, I have requirement to update core properties file. So in case if there are any issues updating the properties file, my server will stop running. Just because even a miss of single existing property will impact. So i am planning to create a temp file and if writing is succesfull i will rename to original file. PLease let me know if there are any other better approaches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write Java properties in a defined order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011108/how-can-i-write-java-properties-in-a-defined-order)

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion. But, can anyone please answer my second part of the question.

Comment: after adding values to properties check if it has all the necessary values instead of storing it in temp file

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code with the following,if you have multiple keys and values make a loop to add them. Also make sure you are putting the right path of your properties file in FileWriter's constructor.

```
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("yourFile.properties", true));
 bw.write(key + "=" + value);
 bw.newLine();
 bw.flush();
```

propertie file is nothing but a plain text file, really your question could be convert to "How do I add the text at the end of the file"